# How to close the dialog for the session using sessionStorage in react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to close a dialog for the session using sessionStorage in react and typescript.

what i am trying to do?
I want to display a dialog (DialogComponent) when user clicks add button (Home component) or click me button (Books component).

Below is my code. It shows dialog when clicking add or click me button. and on clicking hide button in dialog it closes the dialog.

Now i want to do like below.
when user clicks hide button the dialog should close and not be shown again if user clicks add or click me button for the session using sessionStorage.

How can i do it? i am a beginner in using sessionstorage related things. not sure how to do it. Could someone help me do this. thanks.

```
function MainComponent() {
    let [showDialog, setShowDialog] = React.useState(false);
    return (
        <DialogContext.Provider value={{ 
            setDialogOpen: (open: boolean) => setShowDialog(open)}}>
           {showDialog && <Dialog DialogContext={DialogContext}/>
           <Route 
               path="/items">
               <Home />
           </Route>
           <Route
               path="/id/item_id">
               <Books/>
           </Route>
       </DialogContext.Provider>
   )
```

}

```
function Home() {
    const dialogContext= React.useContext(DialogContext);
    const handleClick = () {
        dialogContext.setDialogOpen(true);
    }
    return ( 
        <button onClick={handleClick}>add</button>
    )
}


function Books({DialogContext} : Props) {
    const dialogContext= React.useContext(DialogContext);
    const handleClick = () {
        dialogContext.setDialogOpen(true);
    }
    return ( 
        <button onClick={handleClick()}>Click me</button>
    )  
}

function Dialog() {
    return(
       <div>
           //sometext
           <button onClick={dialogContext.setDialogOpen(false)}> hide</button>
       </div>
    ) 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the session inside you DialogContext setDialogOpen:

```
<DialogContext.Provider value={{ 
    setDialogOpen: (open: boolean) => {
      if (open) {
        const sessionDialogClosed = sessionStorage.getItem('DIALOG_CLOSED');
        if (sessionsDialogClosed !== 'closed') {
            setShowDialog(open)
            sessionStorage.setItem('DIALOG_CLOSED', 'closed');
        }
      } else {
        setShowDialog(open);
      }
    }
}}>
```

Comment: thanks. hm will this not set the session DIALOG_CLOSED to closed if add and click me buttons are closed? and hence unable to open the dialog again even hide message is not clicked.